# Arrays on Python with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a problem with the floats on my arrays.

```
    import numpy
from StringIO import StringIO


matrizgeometrica = numpy.loadtxt('geometrica.txt')    # crea la matriz geometrica a partir del txt
matrizvelocidades = numpy.loadtxt('velocidades.txt')    # crea la matriz de velocidades a partir del txt

#Se genera la matriz de tiempos unitarios a partir de la matriz geometrica y la matriz de velocidades
matriztiempo=matrizgeometrica
for x in matriztiempo:
    for y in matriztiempo:
        if matriztiempo[x,y]!=0 and matrizvelocidades[x,y]!=0:
            matriztiempo[x,y]=matriztiempo[x,y]/matrizvelocidades[x,y]
        else:
            matriztiempo[x,y]=0
```

the error is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lpi2.py", line 12, in <module>
    if matriztiempo[x,y]!=0 and matrizvelocidades[x,y]!=0:
IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
```

I don't know what the problem is but I can't change the values to integer, I need the floats.

Comment: what shape are the matrices?  I'm guessing `for x in matriztiempo` is leaving you with `x` which is an array, not an integer ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is your loop:

```
for x in matriztiempo:
```

This will set `x` to values from the array.  This does not find the position of the values; it just gets the values.

If you want to know the position, the best way is to use `enumerate()` like so:

```
for i, x in enumerate(matriztiempo):
```

Now `x` gets the value as before, but also `i` gets the index of that value in the list.

I think in your case it might be easiest to write the loop like this:

```
for x in xrange(matriztiempo.shape[0]):
    for y in xrange(matriztiempo.shape[1]):
        if matrizvelocidades[x,y] != 0:
            matriztiempo[x,y] /= matrizvelocidades[x,y]
        else:
            matriztiempo[x,y] = 0
```

Usually in Python when we are working with two lists we might want to use `zip()` or `itertools.izip()` to get values, but in this case you are rewriting an array in place using two index values, and I think writing it the above way might be best.  Certainly it's the simplest.

Note that we don't need to test for `matriztiempo[x,y]` being equal to zero; if it is, then the result will be zero for any valid divisor.  We need to check that the divisor is valid to avoid a divide-by-zero exception.  (We could also put a `try:` / `except` block to catch this case, if zero is an unlikely value in `matrizvelocidades`.  If it is a likely value, this is a good way to go.

EDIT: But since this is NumPy there is a better way to do this, much faster.  If we didn't need to worry about zeros in the divisor, we could simply do this:

```
matriztiempo /= matrizvelocidades
```

Since we do need to worry about zeros, we can make a "mask" to solve this.

```
good_mask = (matrizvelocidades != 0)
bad_mask = numpy.logical_not(good_mask)

matriztiempo[good_mask] /= matrizvelocidades[good_mask]
matriztiempo[bad_mask] = 0.0
```

This should be tremendously faster than the solution using `for` loops.

You could also make `bad_mask` like this:

```
bad_mask = (matrizvelocidades == 0)
```

But by explicitly computing `numpy.logical_not()` we make sure that `bad_mask` is always the correct logical inverse of `good_mask`.  If someone edits the line that creates `good_mask`, the `numpy.logical_not()` will find the correct inverse, but if we just had a second expression referencing `matrizvelocidades` then editing one but not editing the other would introduce a bug.